# Why does EasyMock's IArgumentMatcher interface use a StringBuffer?

Tags: java, easymock

EasyMock allows you to create your own matchers so that you can specify what a mock should return for certain inputs. To do this, you create a custom implementation of their [IArgumentMatcher interface](http://www.easymock.org/api/easymock/2.4/org/easymock/IArgumentMatcher.html).

This interface has two methods:

```
boolean matches(Object argument);
void appendTo(StringBuffer buffer)
```

The `appendTo()` method is used for printing a human-readable message if a match fails. Why does it ask you to append the message to a StringBuffer and not to simply return a String? Why not have the following method on the interface instead?

```
String message();
```

Comment: Well, this question can probably only be answered by the interface designer. My guess ... maybe for better performance.

Answer (score 3):

`StringBuffer` here is actually a good choice. If you are using multiple matchers in a given situation, the use of `StringBuffer` allows all of the messages to be consolidated and retrieved a single time.

If you used the `void message();` approach, you would have to call that for each matcher that you were concerned about (which is obviously sub-optimal).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write that message() would have a return type of String.

Comment: When you talk about "using multiple matchers in a given situation", do you mean when you are mocking a method invocation that takes multiple arguments, each with their own matcher?